# Display random view result every x rows

Tags: views, theming

I'm trying to display an ad every six rows of a view. I'm thinking of using another view that contains all the ads and displaying a random result of that every 6 rows of the main view.

Drupal 7 & Views 3.14

I have tried to do this but gotten stuck on the displaying something every 6 rows. Here is my code:

```
...code irrelevant, unedited coded copied from the template file in views module folder...
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row_count => $row): ?>
      <tr <?php if ($row_classes[$row_count]) { print 'class="' . implode(' ', $row_classes[$row_count]) .'"';  } ?>>
        <?php foreach ($row as $field => $content): ?>
          <td <?php if ($field_classes[$field][$row_count]) { print 'class="'. $field_classes[$field][$row_count] . '" '; } ?><?php print drupal_attributes($field_attributes[$field][$row_count]); ?>>
            <?php print $content; ?>
          </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tr>
      <?php if ((($row_count % 6) == 0 && $row_count !== 0): ?><tr>This is the row after every 6th multiple</tr><?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

UPDATE: I figured out a way to print a random result. Just add randomize as the only sort in the view. However, I still can't get the printed view result to be in the appropriate location.

Comment: What happens when you run your code and how is it different to what you want to happen?

Comment: Nothing happens...

Comment: Looking at your code there, there is no $id variable, which is the one you are using to determine row number. What if you try $row_count?

Comment: Yes, changing it to $row_count made a result. I updated the code. However, all of the `<tr>` tags are not showing up, but rather the results are just appearing at the very top of the table, not at the appropriate place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved it by using by using an unformatted list instead of a table.

Here is my code in the end:

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php 
  $numRows = 6; /* Which row do you want the view to appear? E.g. 6 means that rows 6, 12, 18, etc. will have the view */
  if ((($id - ($numRows - 2) ) % ($numRows - 1)) == 0 && $id !== 0):
?>
    <div class="ads views-row"><?php print views_embed_view('VIEW_MACHINE_NAME', 'DISPLAY_ID',''); ?></div> 
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```